# How to parse SQL query with subqueries into the fields?

Tags: javascript, sql, regex

I need to get fields, table and other information from a SQL `SELECT` query.

**My reg exp**

```
/select(.*?)from(.*)/gi
```

**Test queries**

```
SELECT foo FROM table
SELECT foo FROM table WHERE field = 1
SELECT foo FROM table WHERE field IN (SELECT bar FROM bars)
SELECT (SELECT foo FROM foos) FROM table
SELECT (SELECT foo FROM foos) FROM table WHERE field IN (SELECT bar FROM bars)
```

**Expected results** (group 1, group 2)

```
1: foo                    2: table
1: foo                    2: table WHERE field = 1
1: foo                    2: table WHERE field IN (SELECT bar FROM bars)
1: (SELECT foo FROM foos) 2: table
1: (SELECT foo FROM foos) 2: table WHERE field IN (SELECT bar FROM bars)
```

**Actual result** (group 1, group 2)

```
1: foo                    2: table
1: foo                    2: table WHERE field = 1
1: foo                    2: table WHERE field IN (SELECT bar FROM bars)
1: (SELECT foo            2: foos) FROM table
1: (SELECT foo            2: foos) FROM table WHERE field IN (SELECT bar FROM bars)
```

The first three queries matches are good, next two bad, because the first regExp group is greedy. How can I correctly divide any query, if I know that **subquery into the fields is always between brackets**? I think I should use something from:

```
(?=select)
(?!select)
(?<=select)
(?<!select)
```

to find `select` and ingnore next `from`, but I don't know, how.

Thanks

Comment: what you want to extract from the last two queries and what you extracted from the first three. provide sample outputs

Comment: @ran_0315, updated

Comment: Try `select(.*?(\(.*?\))?\s)from(.*)`

Comment: @ran_0315, it seems to work as it should, thank you)